# How to use Mongo aggregate in php to get counters?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to query a collection on an attribute to get a counter for its different values. I group by only one attribute. The request must work regardless of the type of data in the collection.

**Collection**

```
[
    {"name":"michel","bday":"1977-07-21"},
    {"name":"michel","bday":"1985-06-21"},
    {"name":"jean","bday":"1989-10-07"}
]
```

**Output with group by the year of bday**

```
[
    {"1977" : 1},
    {"1985" : 1},
    {"1989" : 1}
]
```

**Output with group by name**

```
[
    {"michel" : 2},
    {"jean" : 1}
]
```

I manage to group on the name but if I don't manage to group on the dates.
For a date I can decide to group on a format (month or year, ...)

I have two problems:

- If my date is a string, I cannot use $dateToString.
- If my date is a ISODate, the function returns an object "UTCDateTime in milliseconds" and not in date format.

I'd like to have one pipeline to manage everything.

**My current pipeline:**

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
            [$project] => Array(
                    [bday] => Array(
                            [$dateToString] => Array(
                                    [format] => %Y
                                    [date] => $bday
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array(
            [$group] => Array(
                    [_id] => $bday
                    [count] => Array(
                            [$sum] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

It s possible to apply dateToString only if the field is a date ?

Comment: Not sure I follow you. Can you please add the expected output ? Are you trying to group on name and group on date separately ? Is your date field contains both string date and ISO Date ? Please add the requested clarifications to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator to check for data type with [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/) operator; if date type [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) else [`$substrCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrCP/) to get the year in [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage.

Something like

```
{"$group":{
  "_id":{
    "$cond":{
      "if":{"$eq":[{"$type":"$bday"},"date"]},
      "then":{"$dateToString":{"format":"%Y","date":"$bday"}},
      "else":{"$substrCP":["$bday",0,4]}
    }
  },
  "count":{"$sum":1}
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply. I have an error with "$type".

> "invalid operator '$type'".

I also try :

```
'$bday' => array('$type' => 'date')
```

I use mongo 3.2.10.

Finally, i use $match stage to determine $type. The solution:

```
{
    $match: {
        "bday": {
            "$type": "date"
        }
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        "_id": {
            "$dateToString": {
                "format": "%Y",
                "$bday"
            }
        },
        "count": {
            "$sum": 1
        }
    }
}
```